# XSLT call-template Recursion

Tags: xslt, recursion

I am wondering how the following templates work in detail. Both return the same results. Both are recursive and both use `substring()` to split the string given by the calling template, but if I debug both templates, `rec1` returns its string at once, while `rec2` returns a value each time, it calls itself.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <foo style="äöb"></foo>
</root>
```

XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" exclude-result-prefixes="#all">

<xsl:template match="foo">
    <root>
        <xsl:call-template name="rec1">
            <xsl:with-param name="style" select="@style"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </root>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template name="rec1">
    <xsl:param name="style"/>
    <xsl:variable name="firstChar" select="substring($style,1,1)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="charMap">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$firstChar='ä'">ae</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$firstChar='ö'">oe</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$firstChar"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:if test="string-length($style) &gt; 1">
            <xsl:call-template name="rec1">
                <xsl:with-param name="style" select="substring($style,2)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="$charMap"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="rec2">
    <xsl:param name="style"/>
    <xsl:variable name="firstChar" select="substring($style,1,1)"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$firstChar='ä'">ae</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$firstChar='ö'">oe</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$firstChar"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:if test="string-length($style) &gt; 1">
        <xsl:call-template name="rec2">
            <xsl:with-param name="style" select="substring($style,2)"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`rec1` Template**

`rec1` recursively builds the value of the variable `charMap` and then outputs it. The only call to `<xsl:value-of select="$charMap"/>` that results in an output is the one coming from the root call of `rec1`, because all subsequent recursive calls happen inside the variable definition of `charMap` (`<xsl:variable name=charMap>`).

Actually, `<xsl:variable name="charMap">` marks the beginning of the definition of the `$charMap` variable but for `$charMap` to be actually defined we need to reach `</xsl:variable>`… although before we reach it we enter a recursive call of `rec1`! All subsequent recursive calls will find themselves waiting for the next recursive call to finish before they can define their own shorter `$charMap` until we reach the last call.

In other words, for `rec1` called with `'Sävsjö'`:

- *charMap0* = S + *charMap1*
- *charMap1* = ae + *charMap2*
- *charMap2* = v + *charMap3*
- *charMap3* = s + *charMap4*
- *charMap4* = j + *charMap5*
- *charMap5* = oe

As long as you don't know the value of *charMap5*, you can't have *charMap0*.

**`rec2` Template**

`rec2` has no `charMap` variable since each call outputs a partial result before doing the recursive call to `rec2`. In the case of `rec2`, no `xsl:value-of` happens inside a `xsl:variable` hence each `xsl:value-of` produces a direct output.

Comment: Thanks! But what happens to each of the values of the variable `charMap` while it is gradually built? And how does the order of the returned value come about? The first value `<xsl:value-of select="$charMap"/>` seems to get, is the value of the last recursion. But in the returned string the order accords the the incoming string. On the other hand: If I would store each value of the recursion in the variable `charMap` but put the recursive calls outside the variable, the returned string is reversed.

Comment: @Ferestes The joys of recursion :) Updated my answer.